# Group in a new list every 60 elements

Tags: python, list, grouping

I would like to receive a dataset of N elements and group it every 59 elements, considering that the first element would have the index 0. The problem in this script is that in the `sample.append(data [i])` part, it groups all the data again in a single list, I would like to divide it as follows. `[[60 elements], [60 elementps], ...]`. Any suggestions for correction?

**Script:**

```
@staticmethod        
def sampleDivision(data):
    parts = int(len(data) / 60)
    collections = []
    i = 1
    while i <= parts:
        i * 60
        collections.append(i * 59)
        i += 1
    print(collections)
    i = 1
    sample = []
    for position in collections:
        while i <= int(position):
            sample.append(data[i])
            i += 1

    return sample
```

**Output:**

```
[68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71, 75, 72, 73, 72, 72, 73, 72, 72, 73, 70, 71, 73, 72, 72, 71, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 68, 68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 68, 60, 60, 61, 60, 61, 65, 69, 69, 72, 73, 72, 72, 73, 72, 72, 73, 70, 71, 73, 75, 78, 80, 82, 84, 87, 84, 84, 83, 82, 79, 78, 76, 74, 73, 72, 72, 72, 71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` function has an increment argument that is useful in this case.

Here is a sample function that does what I think you are looking for:

```
def group_every_n(elements, n):
  L = len(elements) 
  return [elements[i: i+n] for i in range(0, L, n)]

# Get every 60 elements
grouped_by_60 = group_every_n(elements, 60)
```

In this example, `L` is the length of our list, and `range(0, L, n)` creates a generator object (basically, a list that doesn't get created until we ask for it) that spits out every `n`th element at every iteration of the loop. Depending on how long your original list is, the last group will likely have less than 60 elements.

Comment: You did it so easily, I feel so bad rs' Perfect, thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for asking! This was my very first contribution on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Congratulations, welcome, you will be a great member